# Go JS Scrolling Table extension showing error List.elt:i is not in the range

Tags: javascript, gojs

**Objective:**
[need to delete red mark rectangle inside object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1gru.png)
I want to delete Alpha node's item  { name: "D", value: 4 }.

**Note**

1. It working (mean no error found) without [ScrollingTable](https://gojs.net/latest/extensions/ScrollingTable.js)
   Extension
2. Also Tried to solve from [nwoods forum](https://forum.nwoods.com/t/selection-in-field-items/15639/4)  but
   same result (mean same error showing)

**My Procedure:**
To achieve my goal I decide to delete the Alpha node's item  { name: "D", value: 4 } within Transaction from Graph Diagram Model's nodeDataArray.Though it remove the item properly from front-end view and  Graph Diagram Model's nodeDataArray, but showing error in console.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxVrM.png)

Delete Perform Block:

```
 _myDiagram.startTransaction("delete column");
    //get current Selected Table index
    var index = _myDiagram.model.nodeDataArray.findIndex((e)=> { 
            return e.key==currentSelectedNode();
          });
    //get current Selected Table items
    var itemarray = _myDiagram.model.nodeDataArray[index].items;
    //get current selected item, which one(item) is need to delete
    if(_currItemObj != null || _currItemObj != undefined){
        var idx = itemarray.findIndex((e)=> { 
            return e.__gohashid==_currItemObj.__gohashid; 
          });
        _myDiagram.model.removeArrayItem(itemarray, idx); //remove item
    }
    
    _myDiagram.commitTransaction("delete column");
```

**MY Full JS:**

```
var _myDiagram;
function init() {
  if (window.goSamples) goSamples();  // init for these samples -- you don't need to call this
  var $ = go.GraphObject.make;

  _myDiagram =
    $(go.Diagram, "_myDiagramDiv",
      {
        "LayoutCompleted": e => {
          e.diagram.nodes.each(n => {
            var table = n.findObject("TABLE");
            if (table !== null && table.panel._updateScrollBar) table.panel._updateScrollBar(table);
          });
        }
      });

  // support mouse wheel scrolling of table when the mouse is in the table
  _myDiagram.toolManager.doMouseWheel = function() {  // method override requires function, not =>
    var e = this.diagram.lastInput;
    var tab = this.diagram.findObjectAt(e.documentPoint);
    while (tab !== null && !tab._updateScrollBar) tab = tab.panel;
    if (tab !== null) {
      var table = tab.findObject("TABLE");
      if (table) {
        
        var delta = e.delta;
        var incr = e.shift ? 5 : 1;
        if (delta > 0) {
          table.topIndex = Math.max(0, table.topIndex - incr);
        } else if (delta < 0) {
          table.topIndex = Math.min(table.topIndex + incr, table.rowCount-1);
        }
      }
      tab._updateScrollBar(table);
      e.handled = true;
      return;
    }
    go.ToolManager.prototype.doMouseWheel.call(this);
  }

  _myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
    $(go.Node, "Vertical",
      {
        selectionObjectName: "SCROLLER",
        resizable: true, resizeObjectName: "SCROLLER",
        portSpreading: go.Node.SpreadingNone
      },
      new go.Binding("location", "loc", go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify),
      $(go.TextBlock,
        { font: "bold 14px sans-serif" },
        new go.Binding("text", "key")),
      $(go.Panel, "Auto",
        $(go.Shape, { fill: "white" }),
        $("ScrollingTable",
          {
            name: "SCROLLER",
              desiredSize: new go.Size(NaN, 60),  // fixed width
              stretch: go.GraphObject.Fill,       // but stretches vertically
              defaultColumnSeparatorStroke: "black",
              defaultColumnSeparatorStrokeWidth: 0.5
          },
          new go.Binding("TABLE.itemArray", "items"),
          new go.Binding("TABLE.column", "left", left => left ? 2 : 0),
          new go.Binding("desiredSize", "size", go.Size.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Size.stringify),
          {
            "TABLE.itemTemplate":
              $(go.Panel, "TableRow",
                {
                  defaultStretch: go.GraphObject.Horizontal,
                  fromSpot: go.Spot.LeftRightSides, toSpot: go.Spot.LeftRightSides,
                  fromLinkable: true, toLinkable: true
                },
                new go.Binding("portId", "name"),{
                  name: "ItemObj",
                  background: "transparent",
                  mouseEnter: mouseEnter,
                  mouseLeave: mouseLeave,
                },
                $(go.TextBlock, { column: 0 }, new go.Binding("text", "name")),
                $(go.TextBlock, { column: 1 }, new go.Binding("text", "value"))
              ),
            "TABLE.defaultColumnSeparatorStroke": "gray",
            "TABLE.defaultColumnSeparatorStrokeWidth": 0.5,
            "TABLE.defaultRowSeparatorStroke": "gray",
            "TABLE.defaultRowSeparatorStrokeWidth": 0.5,
            "TABLE.defaultSeparatorPadding": new go.Margin(1, 3, 0, 3)
          }
        )
      )
    );

  _myDiagram.model = new go.GraphLinksModel(
    {
      linkFromPortIdProperty: "fromPort",
      linkToPortIdProperty: "toPort",
      nodeDataArray: [
        {
          key: "Alpha", left: true, loc: "0 0", size: "100 50",
          items:
            [
              { name: "A", value: 1 },
              { name: "B", value: 2 },
              { name: "C", value: 3 },
              { name: "D", value: 4 },
              { name: "E", value: 5 },
              { name: "F", value: 6 },
              { name: "G", value: 7 }
            ]
        },
        {
          key: "Beta", loc: "150 0", size: "80 70",
          items:
            [
              { name: "Aa", value: 1 },
              { name: "Bb", value: 2 },
              { name: "Cc", value: 3 },
              { name: "Dd", value: 4 },
              { name: "Ee", value: 5 },
              { name: "Ff", value: 6 },
              { name: "Gg", value: 7 },
              { name: "Hh", value: 8 },
              { name: "Ii", value: 9 },
              { name: "Jj", value: 10 },
              { name: "Kk", value: 11 },
              { name: "Ll", value: 12 },
              { name: "Mm", value: 13 },
              { name: "Nn", value: 14 }
            ]
        }
      ],
      linkDataArray: [
        { from: "Alpha", fromPort: "D", to: "Beta", toPort: "Ff" },
        { from: "Alpha", fromPort: "A", to: "Beta", toPort: "Nn" },
        { from: "Alpha", fromPort: "G", to: "Beta", toPort: "Aa" }
      ]
    });
    function mouseEnter(e, obj) {
    var itemObj = obj.findObject("ItemObj");
    _currItemObj = itemObj.ub;
    itemObj.background = "Gainsboro";
    }
    function mouseLeave(e, obj) {
      var itemObj = obj.findObject("ItemObj");
      itemObj.background = "transparent";
      _currItemObj = {};
      }
}
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
function currentSelectedNode() {
    if (_myDiagram == undefined) return "";
    var n = _myDiagram.selection.first();
    if (n === null) return;
    var currTableName = n.ub.key;
    return currTableName;
}
```